# why is to_char() giving a negative results to a positive number?

Tags: sql, rdbms, netezza

I have the sql code below, it is giving the output I have printed after the query. `DSPNSD_NDC` is a character varying(11). Why do I get a negative results in the `TO_CHAR` column?

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(DECODE(TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC,'',NULL,TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC),99999999999),
               TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(DECODE(TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC,'',NULL,TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC),99999999999),'FM00000000000'),
               DSPNSD_NDC 
        FROM SRW_NDW_TRANS TRANS;
```

### output:

```
TO_NUMBER     TO_CHAR        DSPNSD_NDC
68180021209 -00539455527    68180021209
68382070201 -00337406535    68382070201
10702001801  02112067209    10702001801
50111045601 -01428561951    50111045601
```

Comment: What version of Netezza are you running? SELECT VERSION(); This looks a lot like a bug that was briefly introduced by a change in how the system handles CASE logic.  You can try running the query with "set enable_new_case=0;" before the query.  If you are running them from aginity you need to highlight both the set statement and the sql and run them together. Your query with your data returns the normal, expected results for me on 7.1

Comment: Well i am getting error while setting the variable (ERROR:  'ENABLE_NEW_CASE' is not a valid option name) . Version of NPS is 
              VERSION
-----------------------------------
 Release 6.0.5 (P-9) [Build 24697]
(1 row)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a problem with some internal overflow

```
(68180021209 modulo 2**31 ) + 00539455527 = 2**31
```

But why do you cast from varchar to number and then back to varchar?
Just to add leading zeroes?

Netezza supports LPAD:

```
LPAD(TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC, 11, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that `to_char()` doesn't handle big integers, so you have an integer overflow issue.

One solution would be just to use `cast()`:

```
cast(DECODE(TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC,'',NULL,TRANS.DSPNSD_NDC) as char(11))
```

However, you would then need to pad the number with zeros.

Comment: Thank you for taking this question . But further when i try to use this expression TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(DECODE('68180021209','',NULL,'68180021209'),99999999999),'FM00000000000') . It is not becoming negative .

Comment: @priyaranjan . . . The problem is with `bigint`, not with decimal/numeric.  I think that `to_number()` returns a `decimal` value, rather than `bigint`.